# Django - Parameter passed to the template but it can not use in if statement

Tags: django-templates

I try to pass the variable to another page using GET method in django. It is possible for me to do that, but the problem is that the variable that I passed is not available in the if statement. I try to print out the value then it worked fine. Then I try to use it inside if statement then I come to know that it was not working properly. I have no idea regarding that. Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

This is my views:

```
def test(request):
Test = Photos.objects.all()
ID = request.GET['id']
Context = {
    'ID' : ID,
    'test' : Test,
    'testing' : 3,
}
return render(request, 'test.html', Context)

def tests(request):
tests = Photos.objects.all()
Context = {
    'tests' : tests,
}
return render(request, 'tests.html', Context)
```

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

url(r'^$', 'flashapp.views.home'),
url(r'^play$', 'flashapp.views.play'),
url(r'^test$', 'flashapp.views.test'),
url(r'^tests$', 'flashapp.views.tests'),]
```

In tests.html I have buttons for passing id to test.html using GET method.

This is tests.html:

```
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to tests pages.....</h1>
    {% for i in tests %}
        <a href="/test?id={{ i.id }}">Click For {{ i.id }}</a><br>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

This is test.html:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Test Page</h1>
    <h1>{{ ID }}</h1>
        {% for i in test %}
            <p>{{ i.id }}..........{{ testing }}.........{{ ID }}</p>
            {% if ID == i.id %}
                <p>Test</p>
                <p>Working....ID = {{ i.id }}</p>
            {% else %}
                <p>In else</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
</body>
```

[this is tests.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0mbP.png)

[this is test.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSec3.png)

I suppose to see the "Working....." but, it gone to else block. I have no idea. Help me please!!! 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I edited my original answer based on your comment**

You are passing a QuerySet as your `Test` object instead of an object in the first view, so it doesn't have an `id` property.

When you do this:

```
def test(request):
  Test = Photos.objects.all()
  ...
```

You are getting a collection of all the `Photos` objects into the `Test` variable, which is not what you want, you only want one instance of `Photos`. For that kind of queries, you need to use the `.get` method, that returns a single instance or an exception in case it doesn't find it.

```
Test = Photos.objects.get(pk=request.GET['id'])
```

Your code now should look like this:

```
def test(request):
  ID = request.GET['id']
  Test = Photos.objects.get(pk=ID)
  Context = {
    'ID' : ID,
    'test' : Test,
    'testing' : 3,
  }
  return render(request, 'test.html', Context)
```

Now, for completeness' sake, this would fail in case the ID is not on the database, so we can do something like this:

```
def test(request):
  try: 
    ID = request.GET['id']
    Test = Photos.objects.get(pk=ID)
    Context = {
      'ID' : ID,
      'test' : Test,
      'testing' : 3,
    }
    return render(request, 'test.html', Context)
  except Photos.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("No Photo matches the given query.")
```

Of course, Django has its own shortcuts for these kind of things, so your code can be written like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def test(request):
  #I strongly suggest you don't use uppercase in variable names
  id = request.GET['id']
  test = get_object_or_404(pk=id)
  context = {
    'ID' : id,
    'test' : test,
    'testing' : 3,
  }
  return render(request, 'test.html', context)
```

Comment: Excuse me, I don't really understand. Would u, please specify more?